# bootstrap span customization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using bootstrap.

I am giving a particular html on which I am facing problem.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row well">
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="">
        <a href="blog.html">
           <img class="member" alt="" src="../images/icons/icon1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <p>
       Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. .
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="m-btn blue" href="#">Read More »</a>
    </p>
 </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="">
        <a href="blog.html">
           <img class="member" alt="" src="../images/icons/icon1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <p>
       Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. .
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="m-btn blue" href="#">Read More »</a>
    </p>
 </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="">
        <a href="blog.html">
           <img class="member" alt="" src="../images/icons/icon1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <p>
       Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. .
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="m-btn blue" href="#">Read More »</a>
    </p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

without using well everything looks fine but after using well in `row` tag 3rd `span4` comes to next line.

If I change css of `span` responsiveness is lost.

**My question is** how to put `well` class in row so that the width of the content within `row` doesn't exceed the width of the container?

or

Is there any different way to put `well` css in `row`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use well like that, instead put it in a span, eg.

```
<div class="span8">
    <div class="well">...</div>
</div>
```

Why? Cause `.well` has properties like padding that will modify the scaffolding of `row`

Comment: i want 3 articles in a row. if I use your answer then how to do that in `span8`? and all those 3 articles in `well`.

Comment: you will have to create you own span stylings as they will not follow the bootstrap scaffolding template

Answer (score 0):

it is the padding of well class that is disturbing your design

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it works

Comment: I have done exactly like this earlier, that exceed the width of container.